# Batch script for Prev Month

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have created a batch script that will look for the files which are from previous month(for e.g if current month is Nov then it will look for the files from Oct).
The source from where it needs to look for the files having more than 75000 files. So my script is traversing each file and then checking it if it is from last month.
If file is from last month it is moving them into a temp folder and then it is compressing that temp folder.

Doubts: As script needs to traverse ~ 75000 files it is taking so much of time. Is there any way that script will look for the files which are from last month only. It will not touch for the files which are from current month.

below I have given the code:

```
 echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS


REM this scripts that compress the files in a folder
REM then it move those files on another location
set src_dir=%1%
set back_up=%2%
set save_file=%3%
set ZipTool=%4%

echo Verify System date
echo -------------------
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2-3 delims=," %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get     Month^,Year /Format:csv') do (
    set /a "mm=%%A"
    set /a "yyyy=%%B" 
)
set err=%errorlevel%
if not %err%==0 goto Date_error

set /a pre_month=%mm%-1 
if %mm% EQU 1 (
set mm=12
set /a yyyy-=1
) else (
set /a mm-=1
)



    REM Zero pad month if needed
    if %mm% LSS 10 set "mm=0%mm%"
    if %pre_month% LSS 10 set "pre_month=0%pre_month%"
    echo Prev_Month in yyyymm formate is: %yyyy%%mm%

    REM creating TEMP folder
    set temp=%back_up%\temp\%yyyy%%pre_month%
    REM Creating  Temporary Folder
    mkdir %temp%
    echo %temp% created...
    set /a count=0

    REM moving files into TEMP Folder
    for %%A in ("%src_dir%\*.*") do (
    REM Get month and year from this file
    set  "FileTime=%%~tA"
    set "FileYYYYMM=!FileTime:~6,4!!FileTime:~,2!"
    ::echo !FileYYYYMM! and %yyyy%%mm%>nul
    REM If it is from a current Month, move it to temp.
    if "%yyyy%%mm%" EQU "!FileYYYYMM!" if !count! LSS 10000 (
    set /a count=count+1
    move %%~fA  %temp% >nul ) )

    set err=%errorlevel%
    if not %err%==0 goto Error

    echo Starting 7 Zip Process..
    echo --------------------------
    %ZipTool% a -mx=9 %back_up%\%yyyy%-%pre_month%.zip %tmp%\*.* -ssw > nul 
    set err=%errorlevel%
    if not %err%==0 goto Error

    echo Compresed Files .... >%save_file%
    echo --------------------------->>%save_file%
    for %%G in ("%tmp%\*.*") do echo %%~nG >>%save_file%
    echo ---------------------------->>%save_file%

    if exist %save_file% ( 
    call filesize %save_file% 0
    echo %save_file% has been attached 
    )

    pushd %back_up%\temp
    rd /q /s %yyyy%%pre_month%
    popd
    set err=10
    goto END

:Date_error
echo -----------------------
    echo ERROR: 
    echo Unable to fetch System Date.
    echo -----------------------
    set err=20
    GOTO END

:FolderError
    echo -----------------------
    echo ERROR: 
    echo %yyyy%%pre_month% doesn't exist.Please verify.
    echo -----------------------
    set err=20
    GOTO END
:Error
    echo -----------------------
    echo ERROR: 
    echo Script Execution Error..Please verify.
    echo -----------------------
    set err=20
    GOTO END

:PROMPTS
    echo -----------------------
    echo Prompt Error: 
    echo Prompt missing from the job..Please verify.
    echo -----------------------
    set err=20
    GOTO END

:END
    echo+
    echo Bat Return Code: %err%
    echo+
    ECHO == END process ==
    echo+

exit /b %err%
```

Comment: Maybe you are interested in the `forfiles` command; it features a switch `/D` to define a minimum age of a file, for instance `/D -30`, meaning to do something with files that are older than 30 days; I know it is not exactly what you are searching for, but perhaps this is an option for you as you would not need to parse date strings in batch... `forfiles /P "%src_dir%" /M * /D -30 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE move @path 0x22%temp%0x22"`

Comment: with above command it is moving all the files which are not from previous month. Files which are from last to last month are also moving into temp.

Comment: yes, `forfiles /D -30` enumerates items that are _older than 30 days_...

Comment: so if i need to move only those  files which are from last month.. then..??

Comment: hmm... perhaps you could nest two `forfiles` loops, but since then you will likely needs some date string parsing within outer loop (at least), I'm afraid the performance will not be much better, and `forfiles` itself is also not the quickest thing ever...

Comment: I would like suggestions from others too..:)

Comment: In your script you will need to use delayed expansion inside of the huge `for %%A` loop for all variables you are modifying inside, so you need to expand them like `!variable!` rather than `%variable%`...

Comment: Any reason why this has to be a batch file? I would think a VBScript would be much more efficient. Perhaps read `dir /o:dne` into a text file,  then loop through the lines of text until you find last month, then start copying until you hit the current month. This reduces the number of disk operations which is likely why it takes so long.

Comment: That's a good idea, @Tim! I suggest to use `dir /B /A:-D /O:-D`; its output could even be parsed by a `for /F` loop directly (no need for a temporary file)...

Comment: Are in the 75000 files ones just from previous month and current one? Or may be there older files also?

Comment: My understanding from the comments is that there are files from several months in the folder. So there might be files from June, July, August, etc, but he only wants the files from July for example.

Comment: Agree  with Tim.. there are files from different months also..So in my script it is looking files from previous month( for e.g October months files) so in this case I don't want to touch other months files, reason is if it will check all the files, then it will take so much of time( may be more than 24 hours). So I need that my script will check only previous month files only.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that:

- variable `SRC_DIR` contains the full path to the source directory,
- variable `TMP_DIR` contains the full path to the temporary directory,
- variable `YYYY/MM` holds year and month of the last month in the given format (4-digit year, `/`, 2-digit month), and
- the system date format is `YYYY/MM/DD` (4-digit year, `/`, 2-digit month, `/`, 2-digit day),

the following could work for you:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FLAG="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:-D "%SRC_DIR%"
') do (
    set "ITEM=%%~tI"
    if "!ITEM:~,7!"=="%YYYY/MM%" (
        ECHO move "%%~fI" "%TMP_DIR%"
        set "FLAG=QUIT"
    ) else (
        if defined FLAG goto :QUIT
    )
)
:QUIT
endlocal
```

This echoes the affected files to the screen. If the output is correct, remove the `ECHO`.

---

If your system date format is `DD/MM/YYYY`, replace `if "!ITEM:~,7!"=="%YYYY/MM%"` by `if "!ITEM:~6,4!!ITEM:~2,3!"=="%YYYY/MM%"`.

If your system date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`, replace `if "!ITEM:~,7!"=="%YYYY/MM%"` by `if "!ITEM:~6,4!/!ITEM:~,2!"=="%YYYY/MM%"`.

Comment: I tried with following code based on following variables
variable SRC_DIR Siurce Path
variable TMP_DIR Temporary directory,
variable %YYYY%/%MM% Previous Month and Current Year(i.e 2015/10)
Results: There is nothing to display when i run this code in CMD.
the system date format is MM/DD/YYYY,
     `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:-D "%SRC_DIR%"') do (
  `set "ITEM=%%~dI"`
    `if "!ITEM:~,7!"=="%YYYY%/%MM%" (`
    `move "%%~fI" "%dest%"`
     `set "FLAG=QUIT"`
      `) else (`
      `if defined FLAG goto :QUIT )`
    `)`
    `:QUIT`
    `endlocal`

Comment: Note that I use `YYYY/MM` as one literal variable name, which must hold 4-digit *year*, `/` and 2-digit *month*; I am _not_ using two variables `YYYY` and `MM`;

Comment: I have used Following line of code to get last month and year
`for /f "skip=2 tokens=2-3 delims=," %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Month^,Year /Format:csv') do (`
 `set /a "mm=%%A"`
 `set /a "yyyy=%%B" `
 `)`
 `set /a pre_month=%mm%-1` 
 `if %mm% EQU 1 (`
 `set mm=12`
 `set /a yyyy-=1`
 `) else (`
 `set /a mm-=1`
 `)`

Comment: tried with `set "YYYY/MM=%yyyy%/%mm%"` but again it didn't work and one more doubt at line `if "!ITEM:~,7!"=="%YYYY/MM%"`  `"%yyyy/MM%"` is in light blue color.. I guess it is not getting the value for the variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94308/discussion-between-prax-and-aschipfl).

Comment: Its displaying nothing after modification

Comment: change `@echo off` to `@echo on` and check out the interim outputs; I'm pretty sure the `if` comparison fails due to date format stuff; note that one-digit months might cause trouble (e. g., Feb. `2`, without leading zero, so the variable `YYYY/MM` _must_ contain the date in the _same_ format, including a leading space if there is any!);

Comment: I have added functionality to pad zero for month having single digit.
Below is the result for the If condition it is unable to get the value for **ITEM**  as in 
`set "ITEM=" ` **Nothing has assigned to ITEM**
if "!ITEM:~,7!" == "2015/10" **If condition failed as there is no value for !ITEM:~,7!**

Comment: Test my code isolated, not as part of yours; put `set` commands at the beginning to set the variables `SRC_DIR`, `TMP_DIR` and `YYYY/MM` accordingly; then it should work like it does at my site...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get previous month in YYYYMM format. The line below assume that the date format is "MM/DD/YYYY",
rem so you must modify the "%%a %%c" tokens accordingly if your locale is different:     a  b    c
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do set /A MM=1%%a-1, YYYY=%%c
if %MM% equ 100 set /A MM+=12, YYYY-=1
set "prevMonth=%YYYY%%MM:~1%"

rem Process the files *in date order* from newest to oldest
cd "%src_dir%"
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /O:-D /B') do for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ("%%~Tf") do (
   rem The same note for "date" above apply in next line
   set "fileYYYYMM=%%c%%a"
   if !fileYYYYMM! gtr %prevMonth% (
      echo File "%%f" is of current month...
   ) else if !fileYYYYMM! equ %prevMonth% (
      echo File "%%f" is from previous month...
   ) else (
      echo File "%%f" is the first one two months old or older...
      goto breakProcess
   )
)
:breakProcess
```

Comment: can you help me? using your code for getting prevMonth doesn't seem to work for me.
Here's my code:

`@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do set /A MM=1%%a-1, YYYY=%%c
if %MM% equ 100 set /A MM+=12, YYYY-=1
set "prevMonth=%YYYY%%MM:~1%"

mkdir %prevMonth%`